# Using ngInfiniteScroll to output JSON from a remote source

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, angularjs

I have made a small app using AngularJS 1.4, that outputs JSON data from a remote source.

[Here is the JSON data in question.](http://www.freecodecamp.com/news/hot)

Here is my view - the link to [ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html) comes in at the top of the `container`:

```
<body ng-app="cn" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">

  <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
    <p>Camper News</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div infinite-scroll="feed.loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="3">
      <div ng-repeat="newsItem in myData" class="news-row col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
          <div id="img-container">
            <img ng-src={{newsItem.author.picture}} id="user-avatar" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="news-text col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
          <a href={{newsItem.link}}><em>{{newsItem.headline}}</em></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12" id="link-description">
          {{newsItem.metaDescription}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="bottom-text">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="author">
            <a href='http://www.freecodecamp.com/{{newsItem.author.username}}'>{{newsItem.author.username}}</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="likes">
            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> {{newsItem.upVotes.length}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="timestamp">
            <span am-time-ago={{newsItem.timePosted}} | amFromUnix></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

I am attempting to stagger the loading and outputting of the data using [ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html). I'm just not sure how it would work:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Feed) {
    $scope.feed = new Feed();
});

app.factory('Feed', function($http) {
    var Feed = function() {
        this.items = [];
        this.after = '';
    };

    Feed.prototype.loadMore = function() {
        var url = "http://www.freecodecamp.com/news/hot";
        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            var items = data;
            // Insert code to append to the view, as the user scrolls
        }.bind(this));
    };

    return Feed;
});
```

[Here is a link to the program on Codepen.](http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/qOZrjw) The code that relates to ngInfiniteScroll (`controller` and `factory`) is currently commented out in favour of a working version, but this of course loads all links at once.

What do I need to insert in my `factory` in order to make the JSON load gradually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, by looking at FreeCodeCamps' [story routes](https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp/blob/staging/server/boot/story.js), there is no way to query for specific ranges of the "hot news" stories.

It looks to just return json with a fixed 100 story limit.

```
  function hotJSON(req, res, next) {
    var query = {
      order: 'timePosted DESC',
      limit: 1000
    };
    findStory(query).subscribe(
      function(stories) {
        var sliceVal = stories.length >= 100 ? 100 : stories.length;
        var data = stories.sort(sortByRank).slice(0, sliceVal);
        res.json(data);
      },
      next
    );
  }
```

You can use infinite scroll for the stories it does return to display the local data you retrieve from the request in [chunks as you scroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html).